# Fix object error in Mozilla browser

Tags: javascript, prototyping

I've created a Javacript Library called Tocl. I've tested it in Chrome and Safari and everythigs work properly. But when I test it on Mozilla browser (Firefox, Aurora) nothing happen here. I don't know whats going on here. The console says 'Tocl is undefined' and 'ToclObject' is not constructor. But on Chrome and Safari everythings is ok. Can you help find out whats wrong in my code?

This is my repository:

https://github.com/mahdaen/tocl

https://github.com/mahdaen/tocl/tree/master/sample

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you help people (and yourself) debug by providing a live example with your code from which you strip all the non-essential parts (should be a lot). Most people will give up if they have to sift through 1300 lines of code.

Comment: @Tibos: Sometime people will need help. :) I create that library to help people, I think.

Comment: i think you didn't understand me. I don't question the need for your library, or your need to help debugging it. In fact i was ready to help and even went through your code to do so. Unfortunately your code is too big to spot the problem easily and you should be the one to do the effort of stripping out all the non-essential parts for triggering the error.

Comment: @Tibos: Oh, sorry for missunderstanding. Currently I'm still finding whats wrong in my code. I'll split the code. :(

Comment: Someone wanting to create their own JS library should at least have debugging skills that allow them to come up with a little more than “doesn’t work” IMHO …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to isolate the problem:

```
window.ToclObject = { bug : 'bug fixed'};
Object.defineProperty(window, 'ToclObject', {});

console.log(window.ToclObject.bug); // error
```

I also added a fix:

```
window.ToclObject = { bug : 'bug fixed'};
Object.defineProperty(window, 'ToclObject', { value : window.ToclObject });
console.log(window.ToclObject.bug); // bug fixed
```

The problem is found here: tocl.base.js:1260

PS: If you're interested in how i isolated it:

I copied your code to a file that shows the problem and removed (deleted) code until the error wouldn't show. Then i backtracked to see what exactly i removed between the error showing and not showing and tada... that's where the problem was.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The problem is on `Object.defineProperty`. I've try to remove all define property an fixed. Now it's tested on Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera. On IE I got error since Ajax Request is denied. :( Btw, thanks for help. :)